# Help in downgrading xserver-xorg-core and xserver-xorg-common on ubuntu `18.04` LTS

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, xorg, displaylink

Latest version of display link drivers and xserver slows down external displays to 1 frame per second, if the built-in display is closed.

The issues is described and discussed in length over [here](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/181). As per one of the [comment](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/181#issuecomment-579161974). Downgrading to `1.20.5` of `xorg-server` and `xorg-server-common` helped in case of `archlinux`.

I am not able to figure out similar packages for `ubuntu 18.04.1` and need some details about how can I downgrade the packages.

Comment: Do not downgrade your x-server. It will break your system badly. What kind of graphics card do you have? [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1254049/edit) your question and add the information to it.  Downgrading in Arch Linux (pacman) is different from the apt system, so it is not comparable. That's basically because arch keeps the old packages and you can configure the kernels in a different way. (mkinitcpio)